# Enviando link por email com PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou com dificuldades para mandar um *link* com referências, por *email*, com o PHPMailer.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $titulo = "Parabéns! Surgiu alguém interessado no(a) ".$partner_name;
    $texto2 = "<html>";
    $texto = "Parabéns! Surgiu um pretendente para o(a) ".$partner_name.". Para ver o pretendente, clique no link baixo. <br> ".$link;
    $mail->setFrom('contato@eeeee.com.br', 'PetsMatch');
    $mail->addReplyTo('contato@eeeee.com.br', 'First Last');
    $mail->addAddress($ownerEmail, $ownerName.' '.$ownerLastName);
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($titulo);
    //$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1';
    $mail->Body = "
    <p>Parabéns! Surgiu um pretendente para o(a) ".$partner_name.". Para ver o pretendente, clique no link baixo. <br> <a href='<a href='https://www.eeee.com.br/php/pares.php?type=".$type."&breed=".$breed."&sex=".$sex."&city=".$city."&state=".$state.">ver</a>;
    </p>";
    //$mail->msgHTML(utf8_decode($texto2));
    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    //Attach an image file
    //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Aviso de interesse enviado!";
    }
```

Comment: Poste seu código, assim fica mais fácil te ajudar. (Remova antes quaisquer informações confidenciais)

Comment: E cole o que chega ao e-mail

Comment: @KaduAmaral, coloquei meu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente é um erro de *syntax* do HTML. Repare o teu código:

```
<p>Parabéns! Surgiu um pretendente para o(a) ".$partner_name.". Para ver o pretendente, clique no link baixo. <br> 
<a href='<a href='https://www.eeee.com.br/php/pares.php?type=".$type."&breed=".$breed."&sex=".$sex."&city=".$city."&state=".$state.">ver</a>;
</p>
```

Está com duas aberturas de tags `a` uma dentro da outra, nesse trecho:

```
<a href='<a href=
```

Altere para:

```
$mail->Body = "<p>Parabéns! Surgiu um pretendente para o(a) {$partner_name}. ".
              "Para ver o pretendente, clique no link baixo. <br> ".
              "<a href='https://www.eeee.com.br/php/pares.php".
              "?type={$type}&breed={$breed}&sex={$sex}&city={$city}&state={$state}'>ver</a>".
              "</p>";
```

Procure sempre manter uma boa formatação no teu código, evitando linhas muito longas, assim fica mais fácil encontrar erros.

Comment: fiz a modificação e você mandou, mas estou recebendo o email assim:

"Parabéns! Surgiu um pretendente para o(a) Bizucão. Para ver o pretendente, clique no link baixo. 
<a href='https://www.eeee.com.br/php/pares.php?type=1&breed=2&sex=2&city=Porto_Alegre&state=RS>ver</a></p>"

E não apenas a palavra "ver" e formato ou aparência de link, entende?

Comment: agora funcionou! Onde, exatamente, estava o erro? Que aspa de fechamento era essa?

Comment: Já encontrei a aspa que você diz ter faltado.
Analisei o código, coloquei os dois, lado a lado e analisei...
Outra coisa, ao invés de colocar toda a url, direto, eu não posso colocar ela dentro de uma variável e color só essa variável no corpo do email?
Me entendes?

Comment: Pode sim @GustavoSevero, assim como fiz nas variáveis `$type`, `$breed` pode ser feita outra. Coloque tudo que está no `href` em uma variável `$link = "https://www.eeee..."` e coloque-a no lugar `href='{$link}'`. ;)

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @KaduAmaral.
E por que você usou "{ }" nas variáveis?

Comment: Isso é pano pra manga @GustavoSevero .... Basicamente pra "ajudar" o PHP identificar onde estão as variáveis dentro de uma string. Funciona apenas em strings feitas com aspas duplas ("")